# (Sass) Error in plugin 'gulp-sass' Undefined variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I am trying to make a build of the angularJS project I am using Node 12 but when I try to make the build I got the following error.

build command

```
gulp build
```

error:

[image]

I also try to change my node version with NVM. to (node 9) & (node 8) but still, I get the same error as above. I am not sure what to do any help will be good.

Comment: seems that there's a sass file (scss) that is missing the $layout-breakpoint-xs variable

Comment: no i have this variable in my sass file

Comment: are you using `@import` or `@use`?